# python: shuffle list in respect to other attribute

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I have two lists and I want to shuffle values in one in respect to the attributes in the other. For example:

```
list1 = np.array([1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3])  # spaces for better understanding
list2 = np.array([1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,8,9])
result = [4,5,6, 1,2,3, 7,8,9]
```

I solved this problem by

```
y = split(list2, len(np.unique(list1)))
np.random.shuffle(y)
result = np.array(y).flatten()
```

I want it to work also for the cases when attributes in list1 are not together. Example:

```
list1 = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
list2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
result = [2,1,3,5,4,6,8,7,9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
uniques = np.unique(list1)
shuffled = uniques.copy()
np.random.shuffle(shuffled)

result = list2.copy()
for orig, new in zip(uniques, shuffled):
    result[np.where(list1==orig)] = list2[np.where(list1==new)]
```